# C3881 in Visual Studio, while it compiles without any problems in g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, g++

```
struct Base
{
};

struct DerOne : Base
{
};

struct DerTwo : Base
{
};

struct Joined : DerOne, DerTwo
{
    using Base::Base;
};

int main()
{
    Joined j;
    return 0;
}
```

produces

> Error C3881 can only inherit constructor from direct base

in Visual Studio, while it works fine in g++. Is this code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a GCC bug. What it's doing cannot work, even without checking the standard.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Base {
    Base() { puts("Base()"); }
    Base(int) { puts("Base(int)"); }
};

struct DerOne : Base { };

struct DerTwo : Base { };

struct Joined : DerOne, DerTwo {
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
    Joined j {4};
}
```

With GCC, this allows a `Joined(int)` constructor to be created from the `Base(int)` signature, but it *doesn't* call the `Base(int)` implementation (and cannot, because there are no `DerOne` or `DerTwo` constructors which would call it), so this ends up printing `Base()` twice.

clang rejects it just like Visual Studio does.

Comment: Weird how this bug persisted so long. Thanks for `puts`, by the way. I have  implemented my own version of that up to now!

Comment: A bit off topic: Can I force `Joined` to call a method of `Base`? Or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: @kim366 Oh, you mean a regular method, after construction? You'd have to do that manually, but do keep in mind that you have multiple inheritance, so you have two `Base` instances for which you might need to do that.